# Win32_processor only shows CPU0

Tags: powershell, wmi, get-wmiobject

I'm trying to get performance counter from a computer and until now I used `Get-Counter`, but did some digging around MSDN and found out that the `WMI Object` `Win32_processor` has a property called `LoadPercentage`. But after fooling around I did notice that it is only showing the load value for `CPU0` (1 of the 2 cores). So, is it possible to get `LoadPercentage` from other cores?

Comment: Try `Get-WmiObject win32_processor | Select-Object Name, NumberOfCores, NumberOfLogicalProcessors | fl` : 1 processor, multiple cores, but 1 `LoadPercentage` value. Not sure this class can give you what you want.

Comment: See this Q : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38384658/get-cpu-usage-for-each-core-using-the-windows-command-line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name `CPU0` that you are seeing is a referance to the *processor* name/number not the *core* name/number.

The `LoadPercentage` property is the overall load capacity of each processor (CPU), i.e the sum of all *cores* averaged to the last second ([Ref](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394373(v=vs.85).aspx)).

So to answer your question you will not be able to get the individual *cores* load capacity form the `Win32_processor` `WMI` Object, as `LoadPercentage` has already averaged all *cores* load in the resulting property.

As you stated you can use `Get-Counter` to retrieve this information:

```
Get-Counter '\Processor(*)\% Processor Time' | select -ExpandProperty CounterSamples
```

Result:

```
Path                                            InstanceName      CookedValue
----                                            ------------      -----------
\\fpw10rjol1\processor(0)\% processor time      0            40.0035384989971
\\fpw10rjol1\processor(1)\% processor time      1            27.6965720372529
\\fpw10rjol1\processor(2)\% processor time      2            23.0814596140988
\\fpw10rjol1\processor(3)\% processor time      3            9.23612234463661
\\fpw10rjol1\processor(_total)\% processor time _total       25.0044182009598
```

Comment: I'm using `CPUSTRES.EXE` [from here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vijaysk/2012/10/26/tools-to-simulate-cpu-memory-disk-load/) to simulate CPU load. After applying maximum load only to what i think is `CPU0`, `(Get-WmiObject win32_processor -computer $desktop).LoadPercentage` returns above 90%. When applying maximum load only to the other _core_, it returns below 5%. For information, I'm doing this on a virtual machine.