# Get CPU usage for each core using the windows command line

Tags: powershell, cpu-usage, wmi-query, cpu-cores

Is it possible to print the current CPU usage for each core in the system?

This is what I have so far using powershell:

```
Get-WmiObject -Query "select Name, PercentProcessorTime from Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Processor"
```

Answer (score 5):

It can be be done using the following powershell command:

```
(Get-WmiObject -Query "select Name, PercentProcessorTime from Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Processor") | foreach-object { write-host "$($_.Name): $($_.PercentProcessorTime)" };
```

Also you could create a file called `get_cpu_usage.ps1` with the contents:

```
while ($true)
{
    $cores = (Get-WmiObject -Query "select Name, PercentProcessorTime from Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Processor")
    $cores | foreach-object { write-host "$($_.Name): $($_.PercentProcessorTime)" }; 
    Start-Sleep -m 200
}
```

Then run it using:

```
powershell -executionpolicy bypass "get_cpu_usage.ps1"
```

Comment: `The term 'get_cpu_usage.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Che
ck the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.` This shows on windows-7

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, you can use `Get-Counter` command.

For example:

```
Get-Counter -Counter '\Processor(*)\% Processor Time' -Computer $desktop | select -ExpandProperty CounterSamples
```

<strike>From my testing it's about 4 times faster (atleast on my machine) than querying WMI.</strike>

EDIT:
After testing some more, repeated uses of the query are faster (got mean of `284 ms`) because `Get-Counter` needs minimum of 1 second to get the samples.

Comment: It refers to WMI itself internally.

Answer (score 0):

In Powershell Core 6 the commands have changed.

```
(Get-CimInstance -Query "select Name, PercentProcessorTime from Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Processor") | foreach-object { write-host "$($_.Name): $($_.PercentProcessorTime)" };
```

The script would look like this in Powershell  Core 6.

```
while ($true) {
         $cores = (Get-CimInstance -Query "select Name, PercentProcessorTime from Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Processor")
         $cores | foreach-object { write-host "$($_.Name): $($_.PercentProcessorTime)" };
         Start-Sleep -m 1000
         [System.Console]::Clear() 
}
```

> I just like a screen clear between updates. :)