How to find the number of CPU cores are currently being utilised in a system using Powershell?
Let's say my system have 16 CPU cores.Now i have a use case to find the number of cores are actually being utilized in a system like 2 cores are being used something like this ?
I want to know is there anyway to get the solution using powershell
I am not able to get the actual number of cores that are being currently utilized

all the cores will be used, unless you disable some cores at boot. Even if they're idle there'll still be some kernel code running

This might be what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38384659/6133426

Does this answer your question? Get CPU usage for each core using the windows command line
